# when i clean and build android project in eclipse it delete bin folder and gen folder contents

Tags: android, eclipse

when i clean and build android project in eclipse it delete bin folder and gen folder contents and does not recreate it just create empty folder gen and bin why it is happening I search lot but didn't get solution similar to this issue.

please help me to solve this issue.
after clean build when i run my application it shows this message in console

```
.[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] Android Launch! 
[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] Could not find courieryallatracking.apk!
```

Comment: Why do you think that this is problem?  It's doing exactly what it should do.

Comment: because where I clean and build any android application it remove contents from gen and bin folder and does not recreate it in my eclipse ide

Comment: is there anyone please help me out.

Comment: Those will generated automatically while building your project..

Comment: `not recreate it in my eclipse ide` - you mean you cannot see your source code?  Or do you mean you cannot see the gen and bin folders in Eclipse?  If you cannot see the folders, do they exist on disk?

Comment: @Simon the folders are generated when I clean and build my application but the class file i.e R.java file in gen folder is not generated and also in bin folder it is not recreating apk file

Comment: @ Lokesh Ya I know but it is not generating automatically this is my problem it is only regenerating empty folder i.e gen and bin

Comment: You have an error in your resources, probably XML. This is stopping R.java from being generated. Check the console output when you build.  There are thousands of questions on here already about how to fix problems with R.java.

Answer (score 4):

We face this types of problems sometimes it happens because system having some interrupt in creating bin. If your bin is not recreating following reasons may be like

1. You have some error in .java file or .xml file or you probably have some error other files
2. Project is not proper build. So you should clean and build again. etc.

You should clean and build again project or you can restart the eclipse.
And you can also check our console problem and warning window

Comment: ya I check all this thing but this application working fine on my laptop but not on destop

Answer (score 0):

*clean* should delete it. that's the purpose of that.

*build* should then recreate it.

If it is not recreated you probably have some error in your files

Comment: ya but in my case it is not recreating the folder contents it goes empty and then my console display message as.[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] Android Launch!
[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] Could not find courieryallatracking.apk!

Answer (score 0):

At last I solve the issue because I had not installed build tool and because of that it was not generating gen and bin folder contents.